# how to return the value back from java to nsis

Tags: java, nsis

Please anyone tel me how to call the java class from nsis and return value from the java class to the nsis and and how to use it in the nsis.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a child process and get its process exit code with `ExecWait`.

If you need to return more data than a single number you need to store the data in a file or in the registry and then read it back using normal NSIS instructions....

Answer (score 0):

From the NSIS srcipt, you can run Exec or ExecWait to run the "java" and pass the PropertiesReader.class as parameter to it. Your java program can write the property_value to a file which you can read back from the script.

Here is a link that has a heading "NSIS and Java". You can check that out. Just make sure that the PropertiesReader.class file is in the classpath.